# How to block appimage "Desktop Integrate - AppImageLauncher" notification(prompt)?

Tags: linux, notifications, prompt, appimage

- OS: Manjaro Linux

When I launch an AppImage application, I get this notification.[image: prompt]

Is there a way to block it and run application directly?

Comment: This is not a programming question and as such it is off-topic here. Consider searching for answers on superuser.com. That said, don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for your reminder, will not do it again.

Answer (score 2):

Set the variable `APPIMAGELAUNCHER_DISABLE` to anything, for example `APPIMAGELAUNCHER_DISABLE=1`, and then run your AppImage.

If you set it globally it should ignore the AppImageLauncher entirely even if you're not running it directly from your terminal.

Source:
[https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/issues/78](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/issues/78#issuecomment-466390939)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) from your system.

Comment: After remove `AppImageLauncher`, I can't even launch it: `zsh: no such file or directory: /opt/appimages/listen1.AppImage`. But the appimage is placed in there.

Comment: i dont know why you are downvoted - cause on a fresh system without `AppImageLauncher` installed - this behavior doesnt occur ... also @roachsinai comment makes no sense for me. you dont need the `AppImageLauncher` for starting an AppImage